# conditional stored procedure with/without passing parameter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure which when passed nothing as parameter should return the entire table. But if the studentId is passed, then return her details.
Something like this

```
create procedure usp_GetStudents @studentId int = null
as
  if (@studentId = null)
    select * from Student
  else
    select * from Student where studentId = @studentId
```

Output

```
exec usp_GetStudents -- No records returned though there are records in the table


exec usp_GetStudents @studentId = null  -- No records returned


exec usp_GetStudents @studentId = 256  -- 1 entry returned
```

Just curious to know if anything is wrong in the syntax/logic for returning all the entries of the table?

Thank you

Comment: Which flavor of sql? In tsql, for instance, any `null` comparison is falsy. `null = null` is false, `0 = null` is false, etc. Generally, you'd test for `null` like [`if @studentId is null`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx)...

Comment: Canon you were right. Should have used 'is null' instead of '= null'. Thank you! It worked.

Comment: I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to test for null using `=`, a [comparison operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx). If you're using ANSI nulls, any comparison against `null` is `false`.

Where `@studentId` is *any* value (or `null`) the following expressions are all `false`:

```
@studentId = null  -- false
@studentId > null  -- false
@studentId >= null  -- false
@studentId < null  -- false
@studentId <= null  -- false
@studentId <> null -- false
```

So, in order to test for `null` you must use a special predicate, [`is null`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx), i.e.:

```
@studentId is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Shorter way to do that:

```
create procedure usp_GetStudents @studentId int = null
as
  select * from Student 
  where studentId = isnull(@studentId,studentId)
```

You can't chack if value is null using `=`. 
For your example you have to replace condition `@studentId = null` to `is null` syntax.

Try to change your code as below:

```
create procedure usp_GetStudents @studentId int = null
as
  if (@studentId is null)
    select * from Student
  else
    select * from Student where studentId = @studentId
```

Comment: Can you please explain if there is anything wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Parado, neither mine nor your code works. Any ideas? Your code didn't return any records.

Comment: @bluepiranha I add one more solution. You cant check if vale is null using `=`. I think all of them will be good.

Answer (score 0):

Change the = to an `is`

```
create procedure usp_GetStudents @studentId int = null
as
  if (@studentId is null)
    select * from Student
  else
    select * from Student where studentId = @studentId
```