# Can you change the value of a column that is NULL using a CASE?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I know you can use COALESCE and ISNULL but I was jut wondering if you could do it with a SELECT case.

I had this

```
SELECT (CASE Table.Column WHEN ' ' THEN '1/1/2001' Else Table.Column End),Column2
FROM Table
```

That didn't do anything so I tried:

```
   SELECT (CASE Table.Column WHEN NULL THEN '1/1/2001' Else Table.Column End),Column2
   FROM Table
```

Nothing.

Just Curious. Thanks!

Comment: You mean do an `UPDATE`? Otherwise, you're just missing `IS` before the `NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use the [`is [not] null`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx) predicate like so:

```
select
 case
    when t.Column1 is null then '1/1/2001'
    else t.Column1
 end
,t.Column2
from Table1 as t
```

However, there are functions built specifically for dealing with `null`:

> **1.** [`isnull(check_expression , replacement_value)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)
>
> Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.
>
> ```
> select
>  isnull(t.Column1, '1/1/2001')
> ,t.Column2
> from Table1 as t
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **2.** [`coalesce(expression [ ,...n ])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)
>
> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.
>
> ```
> select
>  coalesce(t.Column1, '1/1/2001')
> ,t.Column2
> from Table1 as t
> ```

Comment: It sometimes slips through my mind that you can use a conditional statement in a Case, I know you could do it! Thank You!

Comment: @Sewder No problem. Also, the reason your second case didn't work is because direct  comparison to `null` (i.e.: without the `is [not] null` predicate) is always falsy ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17534829/621962))

Answer (score 1):

Use `IS` with `NULL`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Column IS NULL 
            THEN '1/1/2001' 
            ELSE Column 
       END,
       Column2
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

nulls require `IS` keyword, not `WHEN` or `=`