# Why SQL comparison with <> doesn't return the row with NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume a table X like so:

```
   A   |   B
----------------
   2       pqr
   3       xyz
 *NULL*    abc
```

When I execute a query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM X 
WHERE A <> 2
```

I expect a result set like this:

```
   A   |   B
----------------
   3       xyz
 *NULL*    abc
```

But to my surprise, I get a result set like this :

```
   A   |   B
----------------
   3      xyz
```

Why does the row with `NULL` value not appear in the result set?

Can somebody explain this behavior ?

Comment: [See this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17534829/621962)

Answer (score 2):

The ANSI-92 SQL Standard states that if one of the operands is NULL, the result of the comparison is "UNKNOWN" - not true or false.

For a good look at how NULLs work in SQL, see [4 Simple Rules for Handling SQL NULLs](http://halturin.blogspot.ca/2010/07/four-rules-for-nulls.html)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea7d2/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE X
    ([A] int, [B] varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO X
    ([A], [B])
VALUES
    (2, 'pqr'),
    (3, 'xyz'),
    (NULL, 'abc')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM X 
WHERE A IS NULL OR A <> 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea7d2/1/0)**:

```
|      A |   B |
|--------|-----|
|      3 | xyz |
| (null) | abc |
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `null <> 2` return unknown in three-state logic which in predicates treats as false.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is not compared using = or <>. Check this [NULL COMPARISON](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191270%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) article. NULLS are compared as `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle NULL ... if any operand is NULL, the result of a comparison is NULL.

if you try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE isnull(A,'NULL') <> 2
```

you may get the results you are expecting (if A is a varchar field) ...

If A is a number field, you could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE isnull(A,0) <> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a visual learner, run this query:

```
SELECT
  a,
  b,
  CASE
    WHEN a <> b THEN 'a <> b'
    WHEN a  = b THEN 'a = b'
    ELSE             'neither'
  END
FROM
  (VALUES (0),(1),(NULL)) a(a),
  (VALUES (0),(1),(NULL)) a(b)
```